# The request could not be completed. (Bad Request) for PullAsync

Tags: c#, azure

I have a working Azure App that uses SQLiteStore, but whenever I change the query for the PullAsync to something that has a Where clause, it gives me a "The request could not be completed. (Bad Request)" exception.

There's existing data in the database.

Works:

```
await syncTable.PullAsync("id", syncTable.CreateQuery(), false, new CancellationToken(), new PullOptions());
```

Does not work:

```
await syncTable.PullAsync("id", syncTable.Where(w => w.otherTableId=="dkdkdkdkd"), false, new CancellationToken(), new PullOptions());
```

Does not work:

```
await syncTable.PullAsync("id", syncTable.CreateQuery().Where(w => w.otherTableId=="dkdkdkdkd"), false, new CancellationToken(), new PullOptions());
```

What could cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make this work by adding a Column attribute and changing "otherTableId" to "OtherTableId" on the server-side code.

Not sure why the server-side code is expecting the uppercase O "OtherTableId"

```
public class SomeTable : EntityData
{
        [Column("otherTableId")]
        public string OtherTableId { get; set; }
}
```

Fiddler Trace:

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 151
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 10 Mar 2017 03:36:28 GMT

{"message":"The query specified in the URI is not valid. Could not find a property named 'OtherTableId' on type 'Backend.DataObjects.SomeTable'."}

GET https://XXXX.azurewebsites.net/tables/SomeTable?$filter=((otherTableId%20eq%20'dkdkdkdkd')%20and%20(updatedAt%20ge%20datetimeoffset'1970-01-01T00%3A00%3A00.0000000%2B00%3A00'))&$orderby=updatedAt&$skip=0&$top=50&__includeDeleted=true

Comment: Which Nuget did you use to get the "Column" attribute on the server?

Comment: @JoakimM using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;